# Game where all positions specify the entire game history

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

I'm looking for an example of a game where, just by looking at the current game state, you can tell uniquely the entire game history.

Are there any games with these properties?

I'm looking for a game with two players, that uses a board, and the larger the game tree the better, but preferably not infinite.

Comment: Well it is easy enough to just invent such a game.  Why do you want such a game?

Comment: I took a crack at inventing a game, but my games are stupid. I believe that if such a game exists, then its game tree can be searched efficiently by programming the rules into a quantum computer. If there's already a game with many known properties, that saves me a lot of work

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for. We certainly could take a regular game and attach the entire history to each position, but a state like "it's the end of the game and Player 1 wins" shouldn't care about the history, and similarly working backwards from the end. It seems, at my first glance, like you would be adding unnecessary details and distinguishing positions that should be treated the same (if only to make algorithms more efficient).

Comment: @MarkS., Since game trees explode exponentially, I expect that simply stating the entire game history as the game state will overload the quantum computation I want to do, because you're increasing the memory needed for any computation by a lot. Similarly, if information is destroyed moving forward, then there's no unique was to retrace your steps once you reach the end. The proposed quantum algorithm would brute force the entire game tree, examine the ending states, and then retrace the entire game tree, using interference to eliminate losing branches of the tree.

Comment: With a small extension of notation, the games Tic-Tac-Toe, Connect Four or Quatro would be examples of such games. The small extension would be to add the move number to each placement of X or O (in the first case), each colored piece (in the second case) or each Quatro piece (in the last case).

Comment: @Jens. Hi thank you for commenting. This is indeed one potential solution. However, since I want to encode the state space, adding numbers increases the state space quite a bit. Take connect four, for example. After your modification, one box can be empty, or contain any number from 1 to 42. The state space has expanded from 42 trits (3-dimensional memory registers), which is about 66 bits, to 42 43-dimensional memory registers, for a total of about 228 bits. I find this a bit undesirable.

Comment: @psitae In the case of connect 4, you are saying that the state space is $3^{42}$ without history, and $43^{42}$ with history. However, if you just remember the sequence of moves used (which column was used), there are only $7^k$ possibilities for a game with $k$ turns, and summing over all $k$, it's $(7^{43}-1)/6$, which is approximately $7^{42}$. Compared to $3^{42}$, this is less than quadratic overhead. (I'm skeptical about a quantum algorithm though.)

Comment: @sdcvvc That's a good point. Thanks. I don't think this kind of solution will work for most games, but this at least gives me a good start. About the quantum algorithm, as far as I can tell, nothing like this exists yet, so you have good reason to be skeptical.